# FlexSlider v2.1 slide start-over

Tags: return, slide, flexslider

When the slideshow ends(when all the pictures displayed) it does not start over, gets stuck at the end.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
$(".flexslider").flexslider({       
    animation: "fade",
    controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
    useCSS: false,
    touch: true,
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,       
    smoothHeight: true,
    slideshowSpeed: 4500,
    slideshow: true,
    pauseOnHover: true  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the folowing line:

```
animationLoop: false,
```

to

```
animationLoop: true,
```

Also make sure that you don't hover the slider as the folowing line of code in your example will make it pause on hover (mouse over):

```
pauseOnHover: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `reverse: true` for starting back to 1